# How to obtain the values used in plot.gam in mgcv?

Tags: r, time-series, smoothing, mgcv

I would like to find out the values `(x, y)` used in plotting `plot(b, seWithMean=TRUE)` in **mgcv** package.  Does anyone know how I can extract or compute these values?

Here is an example:

```
library(mgcv) 
set.seed(0)
dat <- gamSim(1, n=400, dist="normal", scale=2) 
b   <- gam(y~s(x0), data=dat) 
plot(b, seWithMean=TRUE)
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with `gam` models, but have you examined the different attributes of that object? You can look at the names of the objects with `names(b)`. I'm guessing whatever details you are after will be retained within that object somewhere.

Answer (score 22):

Starting with `mgcv` 1.8-6, `plot.gam` invisibly returns the data it uses to generate the plots, i.e. doing

`pd <- plot(<some gam() model>)`

gives you a list with the plotting data in `pd`.

---

ANSWER BELOW FOR `mgcv` <= 1.8-5:

I've repeatedly cursed the fact that the plot functions for `mgcv` don't return the stuff they are plotting -- what follows is ugly but it works:

```
library(mgcv) 
set.seed(0)
dat <- gamSim(1, n = 400, dist = "normal", scale = 2)
b <- gam(y ~ s(x0) + s(x1) + s(x2) + s(x3), data = dat)

plotData <- list()
trace(mgcv:::plot.gam, at = list(c(27, 1)), 
  ## tested for mgcv_1.8-4. other versions may need different at-argument.
  quote({
    message("ooh, so dirty -- assigning into globalenv()'s plotData...")
    plotData <<- pd
    }))
mgcv::plot.gam(b, seWithMean = TRUE, pages = 1)

par(mfrow = c(2, 2))
for (i in 1:4) {
  plot(plotData[[i]]$x, plotData[[i]]$fit, type = "l", xlim = plotData[[i]]$xlim,
    ylim = range(plotData[[i]]$fit + plotData[[i]]$se, plotData[[i]]$fit -
      plotData[[i]]$se))
  matlines(plotData[[i]]$x, cbind(plotData[[i]]$fit + plotData[[i]]$se, 
    plotData[[i]]$fit - plotData[[i]]$se), lty = 2, col = 1)
  rug(plotData[[i]]$raw)  
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for your help. When I reproduce your code up to  `plotData <<- c(plotData, pd[[i]])}))
`, the following message occurs `Error in fBody[[i]] : no such index at level 3`. Any ideas why it does not work?

Comment: The "trace" trick used to work for me. However, it recently failed me. I suspect it has to do with a new version of mgcv package (I'm currently using v 1.8-3), which may require a different "at" argument in the trace function. Can anyone help me on how to get the correct vector for the "at" argument of the trace function? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: @Pepijn see my edit.

Answer (score 4):

Package `visreg` can make effect plots similar to GAM (but perhaps not identical?) and does give the plot components as output as well, formatted as a list. Using plyr one can make a dataframe of the output. Example:

```
plot <- visreg(model, type = "contrast")
smooths <- ldply(plot, function(part)   
  data.frame(x=part$x$xx, smooth=part$y$fit, lower=part$y$lwr, upper=part$y$upr))
```

Answer (score 3):

This will not be a complete answer. All the plotting for `gam` objects is being done with function `plot.gam`. You can look at its code by simply typing

```
> plot.gam
```

in R console. As you will see the code is huge. What I've gleaned from it, that all the plotting is done by gathering relevant information in `pd` object which is a list. So one of the possible solution would be to edit `plot.gam`, using `edit` for example, so that it returns that object. Adding `pd` before last `}` will be enough. I would advise adding `invisible(pd)`, so that this object is returned only if you ask for it:

```
> pd <- plot(b,seWithMean = TRUE)
```

Then inspect this object and search in the code of `plot.gam` for the lines with `plot` and `lines`. Then you will see which of the relevant `x` and `y` values appear in the plot.

Comment: oops, I didn't see yours when I posted my answer. Well, it's a little more detailed anyway....

Comment: @fabians, no worries, I would not have posted mine if I saw yours. I outlined general idea, you have provided the code. Since the question asks for code, your answer is better.

Answer (score 0):

```
## And this is the code for multiple variables!
require(mgcv)
n      = 100
N      = n
tt     = 1:n
arfun  = c(rep(.7,round(n/3)),rep(.3,round(n/3)),rep(-.3,ceiling(n/3)))
arfun2 = c(rep(.8,round(n/3)),rep(.3,round(n/3)),rep(-.3,ceiling(n/3)))
int    = .1*(tt-mean(tt))/max(tt)-.1*((tt-mean(tt))/(max(tt)/10))^2
y      = rep(NA,n)
s.sample <- N
x        <- 10*rnorm(s.sample)
z        <- 10*rnorm(s.sample)
for(j in 1:n){
  y[j]=int[j]+x[j]*arfun[j]+z[j]*arfun2[j]+rnorm(1)  
}

mod = gam(y ~ s(tt) + s(tt, by=x) + s(tt, by=z)) 
## getting the data out of the plot
plotData <- list()
trace(mgcv:::plot.gam, at=list(c(25,3,3,3)),
      # this gets you to the location where plot.gam calls 
      #    plot.mgcv.smooth (see ?trace)
      # plot.mgcv.smooth is the function that does the actual plotting and
      # we simply assign its main argument into the global workspace
      # so we can work with it later.....

      quote({
        # browser()
        print(pd)
        plotData <<- c(plotData, pd)
      }))

# test: 
mgcv::plot.gam(mod, seWithMean=TRUE)


# see if it succeeded
slct = 3
plot(plotData[[slct]]$x, plotData[[slct]]$fit, type="l", xlim=plotData$xlim, 
     ylim=range(plotData[[slct]]$fit + plotData[[slct]]$se, plotData[[slct]]$fit - 
                plotData[[slct]]$se))
matlines(plotData[[slct]]$x, 
         cbind(plotData[[slct]]$fit + plotData[[slct]]$se, 
               plotData[[slct]]$fit - plotData[[slct]]$se), lty=2, col=1)
rug(plotData[[slct]]$raw)
```