# How partial residuals in "plot.gam" are calculated?

Tags: residuals, generalized-additive-model

Take `mtcars` as an example. I build a GAM model between `mpg` (dependent variable) and `disp` and `hp` (independent variables), and plot the partial residual plots:

```
library(mgcv)
gam2 <- gam(mtcars$mpg ~ s(mtcars$disp) + s(mtcars$hp), family = gaussian)
plot(gam2, page = 1, residuals = TRUE, cex = 2.5)
```

In the picture [image: Partial residual plot], I can see for "disp = 400", there is one point; for "hp = 150", there are two points. The X value is consistent with the dataframe:

```
                 mpg  disp  hp
Pontiac Firebird 19.2 400.0 175
Dodge Challenger 15.5 318.0 150
AMC Javelin      15.2 304.0 150
```

There is [an existed question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7795/how-to-obtain-the-values-used-in-plot-gam-in-mgcv) similar to me, and fabians said we can make plot.gam return an object:

```
pd <- plot(gam2, page = 1, residuals = TRUE, cex = 2.5)
```

I think the rug in X axis is `pd[[i]]$raw` for *i*th plot. However, I am confused about: (1) where are Y values stored in `pd`; (2) or are the Y values of "ponits" are calculated, instead of directly stored in `pd`?

About Question 1, I find that Y axis of dots are `pd[[i]]$p.resid`. Can someone give me advice on how these values are calculated (i.e., Question 2)? Why these dots can represent the "partial effects" of the independent variables?